# python SciPy error brentq

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to find the roots of a function

```
from scipy.optimize import brentq
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.polynomial import Polynomial,Legendre
def f():
    return Legendre.basis(3).linspace()

brentq(f,1,2)
```

but i keep getting the error

```
TypeError: f() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

I have no idea whats wrong with it since as far as I can tell, the format of brentq is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the example in the [`brentq` docstring](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.brentq.html).  The function `f` must accept one argument, and return a single value.

For example,

```
In [106]: import numpy as np

In [107]: from scipy.optimize import brentq

In [108]: from numpy.polynomial import Legendre

In [109]: def f(x):
     ...:     return Legendre.basis(3)(x)
     ...: 

In [110]: brentq(f, 0.5, 1)
Out[110]: 0.7745966692411781
```

In this case, there is no need to define `f`, because the object returned by `Legendre.basis(3)` is a callable object that can be passed directly to `brentq`:

```
In [111]: brentq(Legendre.basis(3), 0.5, 1)
Out[111]: 0.7745966692411781
```

And if you are only interested in applying this to Legendre polynomials, there is no need to use `brentq`. You can call the `roots()` method of `Legendre.basis(3)`:

```
In [115]: leg3 = Legendre.basis(3)

In [116]: leg3.roots()
Out[116]: array([ -7.74596669e-01,  -8.32938319e-17,   7.74596669e-01])
```